# How execute code after each dynamic test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, junit5-extension-model

There is a test:

```
package com.cdek.qa_auto.config;
import com.cdek.qa_auto.utils.CdekJUnitListener;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestFactory;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest.dynamicTest;


/***
 *
 */
@SpringBootTest
public class JUnit5Test {
    public JUnit5Test() throws Exception {}

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() throws Exception {
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        TestExecutionListener listener = new CdekJUnitListener();
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    }

    @TestFactory
    public Stream<DynamicTest> test() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("12");
        list.add("123");
        list.add("1234");
        list.add("12345");

        return list.stream().map(item -> (
                dynamicTest("test_" + item, () -> {
                    if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
                        System.out.println("fail");
                        fail("fail");
                    } else if ("12".equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
                        assertTrue(false);
                    } else if ("123".equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
                        throw new Exception("msg");
                    } else {
                        assertTrue(true);
                    }
                        }
                )));
    }
}
```

For example, make a screen for fallen tests.
Written implementation of import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener.

Connect so normally did not work. Does not go into executionFinished.

Basis: JUnit5-Maven-SpringBoot

How do execute specific code after each dynamic test?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests):

> The execution lifecycle of a dynamic test is quite different than it
>   is for a standard @Test case. Specifically, there are no lifecycle
>   callbacks for individual dynamic tests. This means that @BeforeEach
>   and @AfterEach methods and their corresponding extension callbacks are
>   executed for the @TestFactory method but not for each dynamic test. In
>   other words, if you access fields from the test instance within a
>   lambda expression for a dynamic test, those fields will not be reset
>   by callback methods or extensions between the execution of individual
>   dynamic tests generated by the same @TestFactory method.

Thus, you cannot use an `@AfterEach` method or one of the "after" lifecycle callback extensions (i.e., `AfterEachCallback` or `AfterTestExecutionCallback`).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve in your "listener", you may be able to accomplish that in a `TestExecutionListener`, but you cannot register that from within the test class. See [Plugging in your own Test Execution Listener](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom) in the User Guide for details.